# How are asynchronous requests handled by servlets?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, backend

I apologize in advance if this is a bad question.

I'm new to backend development and I'm trying to build an instant messaging service with GAE using java servlets.

And I assume the process for sending a message will be like this:
1. Client send JSON file to servlet.
2. Servlet parses the JSON file and archives the message to the database.

So my question is:

1. what's going to happen if the next user attempts to send another message while the servlet is in the middle of the process of saving the previous message to the database?
2. Because the arrival of user requests are not synchronized with the servlet cycle, will the new request just get lost?
3. Is there going to be some mechanism that queues the request or it's something that I'll have to implement myself?

I think I'm really confused about how the asynchronous request between different functions in a distributed system works.

And, if there any readings that you would recommend for backend design pattern? or just a general introduction?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it is all based upon HTTP.  Depending on the framework you are using for each new request a new Thread will be instantiated.  Read about HTTP and servlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the official tutorial on the subject that talks in depth about the java web technologies , web containers and servlets:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html

But to answer your questions :

1. When another HTTP request comes in , a new thread will be created by
   the web container and will run your servlet concurrently.
2. The new request will be processed concurrently
3. The answer depends on your specific problem , performance and SLA requirements. The simplest solution would be to parse and write each request to the database. If you are dealing with a very large number of simultaneous requests coming in  , i'd suggest starting a whole new discussion on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know exactly what the 'Thread' is? When another request sent to Servlet. The container like tomcat will assign another thread for this request. Every thread is independent from another.

Answer (score 0):

1. Server requests will run in parallel and your code might access/edit the same data concurrently. You should use [Datastore transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions) to prevent data corruption.
2. No, requests are independent and they run in parallel.
3. You **could** use Task Queues in your code to make updates run sequentially, but I'd advise highly against it: first Task Queue will double your requests, second it will force a distributed parallel system to run sequentially, basically negating the whole purpose of AppEngine.

Parallel processing are essential in server programming - they enable servers to process high amount of requests. You should write code that takes this into account - use datastore transactions to prevent possible data corruption in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

in a servlet lifecycle the init() and destroy() methods are called only once - but the service() will be called each time a new request comes and hit the application and a new instance of the servlet will be shared with the request through a different thread . Therefore one of the most basic rules for creating a servlet is not to create global variable in a servlet class.

Your variable is readable/writeable by any other class. You have no control to ensure that they all do sensible things with it. One of them could overwrite it/incorrectly increment it, etc

The is one instance of a servlet, per JVM. So may threads may try to access it concurrently. Because it is global, and you are not providing any synchronization/access control, it will not be thread-safe. Also, if you ever run the servlet in some kind of cluster with different JVMs, then the variable will not be shared between them and you will have multiple loginAttempt variables.